# Problema al fusionar dos objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que fusionar dos objetos en uno, pongo ejemplos simples de lo que necesito hacer:

```
var obj1 = [
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1A',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1B',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1C',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' }
];

var obj2 = { Prop3 : 'Valor 3A', Prop4 : 'Valor 4A', Prop5 : 'Valor 5A' }
```

Y tengo que crear un objeto final que quede con este resultado:

```
var obj1 = [
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1A',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A', Prop3 : 'Valor 3A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1B',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A', Prop4 : 'Valor 4A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1C',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A', Prop5 : 'Valor 5A' }
];
```

Lo que necesito es hacer un 'merge' de objetos en el que cada clave/valor del obj2 sea añadido en cada item del obj1.
He probado hacer esto pero no me devuelve el resultado correcto.

```
obj1.forEach(function(elem) {  
    for(i in obj2) {
        elem['prop_nueva'] = obj2[i];
    }
});
```

Espero vuestra ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira a ver que te parece:

```js
var obj1 = [
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1A',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1B',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1C',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' }
];

var obj2 = { Prop3 : 'Valor 3A', Prop4 : 'Valor 4A', Prop5 : 'Valor 5A' }

Object.prototype.merge = function(obj2){
   let i=0, keys = Object.keys(obj2);
  for( o of this){  
    this[i][keys[i]] = obj2[keys[i]];
    i++;
  }
}

obj1.merge(obj2)

console.log(obj1)
```

te va poniendo clave:valor del segundo objecto al final de cada objecto de la primera lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias, que rapidez. Justo es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Me alegro haber sido de ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer así:

```js
var obj1 = [
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1A',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2A' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1B',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2B' },
        { Prop1 : 'Valor 1C',  Prop2 : 'Valor 2C' }
];

var obj2 = { Prop3 : 'Valor 3A', Prop4 : 'Valor 4A', Prop5 : 'Valor 5A' }

let i=0;
for (propiedad in obj2) {
  console.log('copia', propiedad,'a', obj1[i]);
  obj1[i][propiedad]=obj2[propiedad];
  i++;
}
console.log(obj1);
```

Tienes que asegurarte de que el número de propiedades y el número de elementos en el array sea compatible

Comment: Creo que no vale, esta copiando el objeto obj2 completamente y necesita solo copiar un valor por cada fila.

Comment: Buen punto, no me di cuenta... corrijo entonces